# How can I make a dependent on K8S configuration file?

Tags: kubernetes

I have below k8s configuration yml file but when run `kubectl apply`, it gives me the error  `namespaces "aws-observability" not found`.

I understand that the `aws-observability` namespace is not deployed when deploying the `ConfigMap`.

It can be solved by split this config to two files and deploy the `namespace` first then the `ConfigMap`. But I'd like to put them in one file and deploy them in one go. How can I add a `depend` between these two configurations?

```yaml
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aws-observability
  labels:
    aws-observability: enabled

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aws-logging
  namespace: aws-observability
  labels:
data:
  output.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name cloudwatch
        Match   *
        region <ap-southeast-2>
        log_group_name elk-fluent-bit-cloudwatch
        log_stream_prefix from-elk-fluent-bit-
        auto_create_group true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add separator (---) between two components. I have tested below YAML on my machine and its working as expected:

```
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aws-observability
  labels:
    aws-observability: enabled
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aws-logging
  namespace: aws-observability
  labels:
data:
  output.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name cloudwatch
        Match   *
        region <ap-southeast-2>
        log_group_name elk-fluent-bit-cloudwatch
        log_stream_prefix from-elk-fluent-bit-
        auto_create_group true
```